# Does the Play Console think my test app impersonates my production app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I experience issues with the Play Console review. For the second time I get rejected for impersonating another app.

First for a similar app name, now for the 'High-res icon'.

We uploaded 2 almost identical apps (production and internal test) to Google to be able to use our testing backend. Both environments exist in the same dev account and have gone through different updates that have been reviewed successfully.

Does anyone has experience why this impersonating issue comes up? Is it even possible to impersonate your own app?

I changed the app name to get through the first review reject. I probably need to change the icon for the second reject.